# Cakephp multi level routing

Tags: cakephp, routes

We have some site `example.com` and I want to make routes for different cities (eg.
`example.com/city1`, `example.com/city2`).

We also want to show all other controllers and methods for the current city (eg.
`example.com/city1/:controller/:action`, `example.com/city2/:controller/:action`).

This will look like 2 or more different sites that use the same methods in the controllers but will display different info according to the city.

A router prefix won't work for us, because there could be more than 10 cities, and it must use the same methods in the controllers.

We can add cities from the admin panel.

How  can we make routes that will take cities from the database and display all the links properly?

Comment: Please show what code you've already tried and what problems you have with it.

Comment: @Simon I've tried this one:

$options =  array('city' => 'phoenix|columbus|detroit');

Router::connect('/:city/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    $options);


Router::connect('/:city',
    array('controller' => 'someControllerName', 'action' => 'index'),
    $options);

And add parameter :city to other custom routes, but I want to find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::connect('/:city/:controller/:action/*', array());
Router::connect('/:city/:controller/*', array());
```

This will add a prefix to your routes, but all your URLs will be affected. There is probably an easier way too.

Instead of having example.com/users/login, you will need to have example.com/New-York/users/login.

If you want to generate all these links, let us know what kind of controllers and methods you have.

The routes I pasted work for any prefix (city name)

Comment: Thanks, I've made something similar. But not sure that this is a best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you change your url scheme a little bit, use
`example.com/cities/city1` instead of `example.com/city1`. This change is not only making it easier for routing/rewriting, but it will also rule out the possibility of you adding a city that will accidentally have the same name as a controller!

(Of course there will be some way to keep your original naming scheme, but it will be harder to implement and have the risk of a collision with a controller name)

Once you've got the /cities part in there you can do something like this (sample code taken from [CakePHP Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) and not tested, just to give you an idea):

```
// routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/cities/:city/:controller/:action/:id',
    array(),
    array(
        // order matters since this will simply map ":id" to
        // $articleId in your action
        'pass' => array('id', 'city'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

in your controller:

```
public function view($articleId = null, $city = null) {
    // some code here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need only that routes that I've mentioned in my question without word cities.